# How can I generate spheres equal between the waypoints?

Tags: unity, c#

```
public void duplicateObject(UnityEngine.GameObject original, int howmany)
    {
        howmany++;
        for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < howmany; j++)
            {
                Vector3 position = waypoints[i].transform.position + j * (waypoints[i + 1].transform.position - waypoints[i].transform.position) / howmany;
                UnityEngine.GameObject go = Instantiate(original, new Vector3(position.x, 0, position.z), Quaternion.identity);
                go.transform.localScale = lightsScale;
                objects.Add(go);
            }
        }
    }
```

For example howmany value is 21.
If I have two waypoints it's fine it will create 21 spheres between the two waypoints.

But if I have 3 waypoints it's creating 42 spheres but it should create 21 since howmany is still 21. And it also position the spheres between waypoint 1 and 2 and then from waypoint 2 to 3.

But I want that it will create 7 spheres between waypoints 1 and 2 and 7 spheres between waypoints 2 and 3 and last 7 spheres between waypoints 3 and 1.

[image: Lights]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to divide `howmany` by the number of waypoints.

```
public void duplicateObject(UnityEngine.GameObject original, int howmany)
{
    if(waypoints.Count <= 1) {
        return; // check for division by zero
    }

    // add this division here
    howmany /= (waypoints.Count-1);

    if(howmany < 1){
        howmany = 1; // put at least 1 ball between waypoints ?
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        // Changed the < to a <= instead of adding one.
        for (int j = 1; j <= howmany; j++)
        {
            Vector3 position = waypoints[i].transform.position + j * (waypoints[i + 1].transform.position - waypoints[i].transform.position) / howmany;
            UnityEngine.GameObject go = Instantiate(original, new Vector3(position.x, 0, position.z), Quaternion.identity);
            go.transform.localScale = lightsScale;
            objects.Add(go);
        }
    }
}
```